# Compare Java arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to compare the names of the roomtypes in a simple Java program but I can't get it to work.

So far I have this:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RoomType[] ar = new RoomType[10];
    String s = "";
    String duplicate = "";

    ar[0] = new RoomType("Standaard", 2, 60.0);
    ar[1] = new RoomType("DeLuxe", 2, 85.0);
    ar[2] = new RoomType("DeLuxe", 4, 125.0);
    ar[3] = new RoomType("Hiker", 2, 35.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar[i] != null) {
            s += ar[i] + "\n";
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < ar.length -1; j++) {
            if (ar[i] == ar[j] && ar[i] != null && ar[j] != null) {
                duplicate = ar[i] + " has the same name as " + ar[j];
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("These are the roomtypes: \n" + s + "\n");
    System.out.println(duplicate);
}
```

}

I want to compare the names (the first elements in the arrays) of all `ar[]`'s and if there are doubles I need a sysout that gives the position (`ar[]`) of the doubles. The method getTypeName() is in a different class RoomType.

Comment: Ok so first you have your `for` loops kind of wrong. You have the right concept of running through the array but you are not at all calling the method `getTypeName()` to compare. The statement `ar[i] == ar[j]` is comparing the two objects. You should override `equals(Object obj)` in your `RoomType` class and use that to determine whether they are equal or not. If not that change that statement i said before to `ar[i].getTypeName().equals(ar[j].getTypeName())` to compare the names

Comment: I tried to change the statement but I get a nullpointerexception.

Comment: Well of course you do :P. Switch around the check for nulls in your if statement to first check if they are null.

Comment: Ofcourse.... :P The problem now is that the outcome is that there's a double in "Hiker", when the double has to be in "DeLuxe". And how can I get it to show the position of the double instead of the name?

Comment: I posted an answer that should help a little

Comment: I'm gonna try tomorrow after some sleep, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I interpreted as what you are asking for:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
{
  if(ar[i] != null)
    s += ar[i].getTypeName()+"\n";
 for(int j = 1; j < ar.length; j++)
  {
    if(ar[i] != null && ar[j] != null && ar[i].getTypeName().equals(ar[j].getTypeName()))
    {
        duplicate += i+" has the same name as "+j+"\n";
    }
  }
}
System.out.println("These are the roomtypes: \n"+s+"\n");
System.out.println(duplicate);
```

Answer (score 2):

> "I want to compare the names (the first elements in the arrays) of all
>   ar[]'s and if there are doubles I need a sysout that gives the
>   position (ar[]) of the doubles"

It seems like your approach is wrong. Your `RoomType` could implement `equals`and `hashcode` based on your requirements and then you can add them to a data structure that doesn't permit duplicates like `java.util.Set`. Trying to insert a duplicate element to a Set will return `false` and this could help you. Unless you are practicing/playing around with arrays in Java, standard data structures will solve these kind of problems for you.

Comment: It's for a school assignment, we have to test if there are names of rooms which are the same. We haven't done anything with hashcode yet so I doubt that's what they want me to do

Comment: Programming equals and hashCode to only take in to account a single aspect of an object isn't a good suggestion. To do this with a Set, use a TreeSet with a custom comparator.

Comment: Its not a good idea to implement equals and hashcode for the given example. using an arraylist would be a better option, if thats permitted in the homework. Or the option RadioDef suggested can help too.

Comment: @SonalKhodiyar how is arraylist a better Option? - this guy is obviously looking for a solution for his homework which should use probably only arrays and this is not the purpose of SO. Unaware of that, I proposed a solution which involves a datastructure most naturally suited to capture duplicate in real world. Whether equals/hashcode is OK here depends upon his object. In Radiodef's suggestion also, he could end up with a comparator that is not in line with equals which is not a good practice

Comment: That's the reason I said "if that's permitted in the homework". He said that they havent touched hashcode, that's the reason I suggested Arraylist. Arraylist is an easier way to implement the current problem. the ideal use of equals and hashcode would be to compare if the two lists are same or not. He wants to find duplicates.

Comment: (*Girl) I'm supposed to do it with array only, but thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to note:

- It is far more space/time efficient to use a `StringBuilder`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html to "grow" Strings.
- "==" and "!=" compare Strings by reference instead of value. Use `.equals()` instead.
- We can use a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>` to efficiently store duplicate info. We map type names to positions in the array. I've written a function below:

---

```
public void printDuplicateInfo(RoomType[] roomList) {

  HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
  for(int i = 0; i < roomList.length; i++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> pos;
    String name = roomList[i].getTypeName()
      if(!map.containsKey(name))
        pos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      else
        pos = map.get(name);
    pos.add(i);
    map.put(name, pos);
  }

  Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
  StringBuilder strBuf = new StringBuilder();
  strBuf.append("***Duplicate Info***\n");
  for(String name : set) {
    ArrayList<Integer> pos = map.get(name);
    int size = pos.size();
    if(size == 1)
      continue;
    strBuf.append(name).append(": present at indices ");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      strBuf.append(pos.get(i)).append(" ");

    strBuf.append("\n")
  }

  System.out.print(strBuf);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely check this out

Answer (score -1):

Try using ArrayList, and .Contains to compare. It will make your life easier and get you introduced to more datastructures in Java.

All the best with the school. this is a great place to grow. Be active :)

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely look into more datastructures.